# How to get and send _token from an html page when submitting a form request to laravel 5 app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-5, csrf-protection

I have an app with the client side written in HTML and Angularjs and the server-side in Laravel 5. Each time I submit my form, I send the models using `$http` to a route in my laravel 5 app but I keep having the error

```
production.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException'...
```

I know it is because `_token` is absent among my models. But how do I get it since my form page is purely in HTML and Javascript.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite common problem. You need to use  tag and add the header X-CSRF-TOKEN like this

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

More info at http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-protection